# Flutter build macOS spams a crazy amount of warnings

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a flutter app for macOS. If I run it locally, I get all the warning but the app runs. When I build it for release, I get a crazy amount of them and the build does not finish because of too many warnings. Did anyone else encounter this? Here are some of the warnings I get:

```
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/status/internal/status_internal.h:22:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/strings/cord.h:75:
  return bit_cast<int16_t>(FromHost16(bit_cast<uint16_t>(x)));
                                      ^
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/server_callback.cc:21:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:33:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/iomgr/error.h:27:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/status/status.h:57:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/container/inlined_vector.h:53:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/container/internal/inlined_vector.h:30:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/container/internal/compressed_tuple.h:40:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/utility/utility.h:50:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/base/internal/invoke.h:64:
/Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/meta/type_traits.h:559:8: warning: builtin __has_trivial_copy is deprecated; use __is_trivially_copyable instead [-Wdeprecated-builtins]
      (__has_trivial_copy(ExtentsRemoved) || !kIsCopyOrMoveConstructible) &&
       ^
          bool, type_traits_internal::is_trivially_copyable_impl<T>::kValue> {};
                                      ^
                                   ^
      is_trivially_destructible<ExtentsRemoved>::value &&
      ^
          bool, type_traits_internal::is_trivially_copyable_impl<T>::kValue> {};
                                      ^
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/server_callback.cc:21:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:33:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/iomgr/error.h:27:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/status/status.h:59:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/status/internal/status_internal.h:22:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/strings/cord.h:75:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/base/internal/endian.h:22:
                  type_traits_internal::is_trivially_copyable<Source>::value &&
                                        ^
inline constexpr Dest bit_cast(const Source& source) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/server_callback.cc:21:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:33:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/macos/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/iomgr/error.h:27:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/status/status.h:59:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/status/internal/status_internal.h:22:
In file included from /Users/andreimac/Developer/FlutterApp/mac_menu/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/abseil/absl.framework/Headers/strings/cord.h:75:
  return bit_cast<int32_t>(FromHost32(bit_cast<uint32_t>(x)));
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
```

Please note that those warning are spammed every second of the build phase.
Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

please delete flutter_mint package from the pubspec.yaml